# How to set maximum number of external processes the program can start at the same time?

Tags: c#, windows, process, queue

I need to run an external program for every PDF file in specified directory.

The problem is - **how to limit the number of external program processes** to user-specified value? I run it in the loop, like this:

```
foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"path\program.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = previouslySetArguments;
    p.Start();
}
```

Now the problem is that there is sometimes a really huge amount of files and with that code, all processes would be ran at the same time. It really slows the machine down.

Other idea is to put `p.WaitForExit();` after the `p.Start();` but then it would run only one process at a time, which on the other hand - slows down the whole work :)

What is the easiest way to limit processes number to run the exact amount of them at the same time? I want to let the user decide.

Let's say I want to run maximum 5 processes at once. So:
 - first 5 processes starts in more-or-less the same time for first 5 files in the directory
 - when one of them (doesn't matter, which) ends work, the next one starts - for the next file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spawn processes, but only 5 at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360720/spawn-processes-but-only-5-at-a-time)

Comment: @AustinSalonen - Why does the version of .NET matter?

Comment: @Ramhound:  TPL could be a nice, clean option but wouldn't be available if OP is using an older version of .Net.

Comment: @Austin-Salonen: .NET 4.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would look into a the producer-consumer model of queuing.  It's intended to do pretty much exactly this, and there are lots of good examples that you can modify to suit your needs.

Here's an example:
[C# producer/consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656404/c-sharp-producer-consumer)

And another example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
(this last one is for 4.5, but still valid IMO)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I tried the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360720/spawn-processes-but-only-5-at-a-time), but - strange thing - I couldn't get them to work. I admit, I was in a hurry, I could made some mistakes...

For now, the quickiest and simpliest (and ugliest) method I've found is just a loop, like the code below. It works with the test program that just calls `Thread.Sleep()` with given command line argument as miliseconds.

Now, **please, explain me, why is it not a good solution** - I assume it is not the correct way (not only because the code is ugly), even if it works with this test example.

```
class Program
{
    // hardcoded, it's just a test:
    static int activeProcesses = 0;
    static int finishedProcesses = 0;
    static int maxProcesses = 5;
    static int runProcesses = 20;

    static string file = @"c:\tmp\dummyDelay.exe";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        while (activeProcesses + finishedProcesses < runProcesses)
        {
            if (activeProcesses < maxProcesses)
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                p.Exited += new EventHandler(pExited);
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = file;
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = rnd.Next(2000, 5000).ToString();
                p.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Started: {0}", p.Id.ToString());
                activeProcesses++;
            }
        }

    }

    static void pExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finished: {0}", ((Process)sender).Id.ToString());
        ((Process)sender).Dispose();
        activeProcesses--;
        finishedProcesses++;
    }
}
```